# ¿Cómo realizo una suma en una consulta jerárquica en el SGBD Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Tengo una [BD en oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c101/14) con empleados agrupados por áreas.
Cuando trato de obtener las sub-sumas de empleados por área mediante la consulta

```
SELECT rpad( ' ', 1*level, '===' )
       ||
       case when  level> 1 then '>'
       else '+' end
       ||
       dept_name dept_name
      ,sum(employees)
      , employees
FROM dept
START WITH parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR dept_id = parent_id;
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Adjunto un [enlace](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c101/13) por si alguien quisiera ayudar y no tuviera acceso a un entorno configurado.

### Salida esperada

```
------------------------------------------------
|          DEPT_NAME | EMPLOYEES |SUM EMPLOYEES|
|--------------------|-----------|-------------|
|  +IT               |       100 |          178|
|  =>DEVELOPMENT     |        12 |          30 |
|  ==>PL/SQL         |         2 |           2 |
|  ==>Java           |         1 |           2 |
|  ===>Dukescript    |         1 |           1 |
|  ==>SQL            |        11 |          11 |
|  ==>C++            |         3 |           3 |
|  =>SUPPORT         |        15 |          15 |
|  =>TEST            |        25 |          33 |
|  ==>Functional     |         3 |           3 |
|  ==>Non Functional |         5 |           5 |
------------------------------------------------
```

### Avances

Sin especificar el nivel obtengo el árbol duplicado

```
select dept_name, employees, tot_employees 
from (select 
           employees,
           rpad( ' ', 1*level, '===' )
       ||
       case when  level> 1 then '>'
       else '+' end
       ||
       dept_name dept_name,
           level lev,
           sum(employees) over(partition by connect_by_root
                                           (dept_id)
                               ) tot_employees
      from dept
    connect by prior dept_id = parent_id)
    ;
```

pero usando

```
select dept_name, employees, tot_employees 
from (select 
           employees,
           rpad( ' ', 1*level, '===' )
       ||
       case when  level> 1 then '>'
       else '+' end
       ||
       dept_name dept_name,
           level lev,
           sum(employees) over(partition by connect_by_root
                                           (dept_id)
                               ) tot_employees
      from dept
    connect by prior dept_id = parent_id)
    where lev=1;
```

se destruye el árbol que estaba imprimiendo.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: podrías poner la salida que esperas obtener?

Comment: Listo, ya hice la suma a mano.

Answer (score 2):

Esta respuesta es una aproximación a la solución deseada:

```
SELECT PARENT, DEPT_NAME, SUM(employees)
FROM (
    SELECT CASE PARENT_ID WHEN 1 THEN DEPT_ID
       ELSE PARENT_ID END PARENT,
       rpad( ' ', 1*level, '===' )
       ||
       case when  level> 1 then '>'
       else '+' end
       ||
       dept_name dept_name      
      ,EMPLOYEES
    FROM dept
    START WITH parent_id is null
    CONNECT BY PRIOR dept_id = parent_id)
GROUP BY ROLLUP(PARENT, dept_name)
ORDER BY PARENT, dept_name;
```

La clave es el uso de una subcláusula de GROUP BY llamada ROLLUP, que genera subagregados que en este caso son subtotales para cada una de las áreas, que aparecen al final de cada una.

El detalle es que la agrupación no agrupa correctamente las áreas que estén en un nivel mayor a dos, por ejemplo `Dukescript` no está asignado a `DEVELOPMENT` sino a `Java`. El `CASE WHEN` lo uso para que las áreas principales también sean contadas. Espero que esto te pueda dar una idea y modificando la consulta puedas llegar a la solución correcta.

Comment: Que inteligente de tu parte poner un avance :D Muchas gracias lo revisaré con calma :)

Answer (score 0):

No conozco la sintaxis de Oracle en particular, pero en SQL, para poder utilizar una función de agregación tienes que agrupar por los campos que no están en la función (`GROUP BY`).

Puedes ver por ejemplo [aquí](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/group_by.php), que explica como usar el `GROUP BY` en Oracle.

De todas formas, poner `sum(employees)` y `employees` en la misma consulta no creo que tenga el efecto que tu quieres, va a darte lo mismo en las dos columnas. Deberías hacer una "**sub-query**" que te devuelva la suma de los empleados de los departamentos que son hijos del actual...

Comment: Desafortunadamente no se trata de una consulta simple con función de agrupación, se trata de una consulta avanzada, (jerárquica), he visto consultas jerárquicas en varios manejadores, no únicamente en Oracle. Voy a compartir mis avances, la suma no va tan mal... pero el árbol se ha destruido :(

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro, las consultas jerárquicas no son "oficiales" según el estandar SQL, son propias del fabricante (en este caso Oracle). DB2 las tiene también, pero mysql no. A partir de ahi, el comportamiento que debe darse con la función GROUP BY depende de lo que se haya hecho. Y me temo que en este caso Marcos tiene razón. Aunque reconozco que la utilidad de la función es muy alta.

Comment: @RaulLuna en verdad que existen en mysql: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74fc16/27

Comment: Y existe en ANSI SQL desde 1992 mediante full outer joins: http://advancedhierarchicalprocessing.ulitzer.com/node/1764314 auqnue en el ANSI SQL de 1999 se soportaban las consultas jerárquicas para otorgar privilegios http://dbis-informatik.uibk.ac.at/files/ext/lehre/ss11/vo-ndbm/lit/ORel-SQL1999-IBM-Nelson-Mattos.pdf